# Can eclipse find occurences of a method signature having a particular annotation?

Tags: eclipse, search

For example, many of my classes have a *getEntity()* accessor, which can be found via Java Search by specfiying the Search string `getEntity()`, and Search For `Method`. But I need to narrow this to only the methods that have the annotation *@OneToOne*.

I tried a few wild guesses in the Search string to no avail. For example: `getFoobar() @OneToOne` and `@OneToOne getFoobar()`. Is there a anyway to do this?

(Resorting to a regular expression search seems error prone because annotation syntax uses all the same characters that delimit methods.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more like a (partial) workaround than actual solution, but you could use the References-search to show you all the places in your project (or workspace) where the annotation is used. Note that this will list all occurrences of the selected item (class, method, member variable or annotation), not only those occurring in methods:

Select the annotation by double-clicking on an occurrence (or "paint" it with shift+arrow keys or with mouse) and select References->Project in the context menu (right-click). Shift+Ctrl+G is the default short cut to search entire workspace (all open projects), you can also set your own short cut for project-wide search in Window->Preferences->General->Keys (if you prefer to keep your hands on the keyboard and need only project-wide search).

Comment: That's actually quite helpful once I sort the Reference-search result by name.